# Jquery loop interval

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a series of animation co-ordinates stacked inside a loop. I want to run **ALL** co-ordinates over a certain period and when it finishes going through all it must start from the top and run through them again.

The loop works, but it doesn't start from the first co-ordinates (`'top':'+=50'` and `'left':'+=300'`) when it goes through the loop.

```
var port = $('span.view-port'),
    yoyoDuration = 100,
    run = setInterval( function (){
            port.animate({
            'top': '+=50',
            'left': '+=300'
            }, {duration: 1500}) /* -- first co-ordinates -- */
            .animate({
            'top': '+=80',
            'left': '-=300'
            }, {duration: 1500})
            .animate({
            'left': '+=300',
            }, {duration: 2500})
            .animate({
            'top': '-=80',
            'left': '-=300'
            }, {duration: 2500})
            .animate({
            'top': '+=150',
            'left': '+=300'
            }, {duration: 2500})
            .animate({
            'top': '+=50',
            'left': '-=300'
            }, {duration: 2500}) /* -- last co-ordinates -- */
    }, 500);

    setTimeout(function () {
    }, yoyoDuration);
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/simomultimedia/NXSVk/1/

Comment: If your last animation doesn't put the object back where you want the loop to start again, then you will have to either add a new last step to your animation that puts it back in the right place or just set it back into the right place with `.css()`.  Since you're using `+=` and `-=`, those are relative to the current location.  So, to make the current location what you want at the start of each iteration, you have to make the numbers do that.

Comment: ahh now I see, I was focusing on the loop whereas the the solution is on the last animation. Thanks man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a mathematical error. If you want your last animate to move the element to the start position, change it to:

```
.animate({
    'top': '-=200',
    'left': '-=300'
}
```

But if you want it to move to start after you **current** last animation then add the following animate after that:

```
.animate({
    'top': '-=250'
}
```